# What is the different between the two methods to get LineRenderer positons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first one using List

This method is not giving any errors but returns a long list of the same position 0,0,0
If there are for example 5000 items they are all 0,0,0

```
List<Vector3> GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        lineRendererPositions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount].ToList();
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(lineRendererPositions.ToArray());


        //the points returned are in world space
        return lineRendererPositions;
    }
```

And this method is Vector3[] and it's working fine and return the linerenderer positions :

```
Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace1()
    {
        var positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }
```

Why when using List, it return all the positions the same 0,0,0 and if using array it returns the correct positions from the linerenderer ?

How can I use a List to get the positions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that if you use

```
lineRendererPositions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount].ToList();
lineRenderer.GetPositions(lineRendererPositions.ToArray());
```

- You create a new array with length of `lineRenderer.positionCount` where all elements have the default value (`0,0,0`).
- you then make a **copy** of that array and convert it as a `List` using [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist)
- you then again make a **second copy** of the `List` and convert it back to an array using [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray)
- This second copied array is filled by [`GetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html)

**BUT** what you return is the `List` which was never filled by `GetPositions` since you only filled the copied array.

Have in mind that [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is a [**`struct`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and thereby it is a [**value type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) and not a reference! Your code *would* "work" (yet still extremely inefficient) if the elements of the list/array where reference types since then all the array/list instances would reference the exact same element instances. But here this is not the case, they refer to copied value instances which are in no way linked between the copied list/array.

---

If you really need to return a `List` you should stick to the array until the very end of the method and use e.g.

```
List<Vector3> GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
{
    var positionsArray = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
    
    lineRenderer.GetPositions(positionsArray);
    
    return new List<Vector3>(positionsArray);
}
```

Have in mind though that this always creates a copy of the array and is worse in performance than just returning an array.

---

And finally a general note

The method is a bit misleading. Yes it returns positions in world space **but** only, if the LineRenderer actually is set to [`useWorldSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-useWorldSpace.html)! If it is set to use local space the GetPositions returns local space positions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want a list vs. an array? The [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) have this method only returning a `Vector3[]`, `NativeArray<Vector3>` or `NativeSlice<Vector3>`. If you **really** want you can convert the array to a list.

```
List<Vector3> GetLinePointsInWorldSpace1()
{
    Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
    //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
    lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);
    
    List<Vector3> yourPosList = new List<Vector3>(positions);


    //the points returned are in world space
    return yourPosList;
}
```

What is the use case of having a `list` vs. `array` might I ask? The main reason your other snippet is failing is you are using a `.ToArray()` on an array. You most likely need the `System.Linq` function `.ToList();`.